# Understanding auto in css grids

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am pretty new to Web development and I am trying to learn CSS grids. While learning the CSS grid I tried to make one simple layout. It has one header section, one menu section, one sidebar section, and one footer section.

I used **auto**  while defining grid template rows for the 2nd row, and gave conatiner height as 100%, so that 2nd row will stretch fully in the remaining space left by row 1 and 2.
But it didn't work that way, i am trying to figure out why 2nd row is not stretching vertically in the remaning space left.

Here is the conatiner css in which i defined the 2nd row as auto and conatiner height as 100%.

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
}
```

fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/791vtd4z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on Terry's answer, you can achieve your desired result by giving `body` a height of `100vh`, you could change the height of `.container` to `100vh`, or you could give `html` *and* `body` a height of `100%` (and keep the `100%` height of `.container`).

This is because 100vh gives an element the full height of the viewport *regardless of the height of its parents*, while setting an element's full height using a percentage (i.e. `100%`) means the element takes the full height of its parent, whatever that is. So an element with a height of 100% could still be zero, if its parent has no height.

To put this another way, when setting an element's height to `100%` all of its parents need to be `100%` as well for that element to take up the full viewport.

```css
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

title {
    display: none;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
}

.Header {
    background-color: beige;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.Menu {
    background-color: red;
}

.Sidebar {
    background-color: burlywood;
    grid-column: 2/-1;
}

.Footer {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="Header">Header</div>
        <div class="Menu">Menu</div>
        <div class="Sidebar">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="Footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because you did not give `body` a fixed height, yet you have `.container` a relative height: therefore, when the child `.container` simply stretches to its content height and not any further, since there's nothing absolute to compare against by using `100%` (ask yourself: "100% of what?").

A solution will be to set `.container { min-height: 100vh; }` to fix that, which tells the element to at least be as tall as the viewport, and allow it to grow should the content inside menu or sidebar grow beyond what the viewport can contain.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

title {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
}

.Header {
  background-color: beige;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.Menu {
  background-color: red;
}

.Sidebar {
  background-color: burlywood;
  grid-column: 2/-1;
}

.Footer {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Header">Header</div>
  <div class="Menu">Menu</div>
  <div class="Sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="Footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```